# preg_match, скобки и ограничитель слова?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как заставить работать код?

```
if (preg_match("/\bпривет (мир)\b/iu", "привет (мир)")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

preg_quote не помогает.

Comment: if (preg_match("/\bпривет (мир)\b/iu", "привет (мир)")) {

    что за /iu?

Comment: регистронезависимый поиск + поддержка кириллицы

Comment: и чего со скобками? экранируйте их, если надо чтобы они были простыми скобками, а не группами и т.п. _зы: зачем в данном коде if-else ?_

Comment: "preg_quote не помогает." для кого написано? этот код часть другого...

Comment: Похоже вам нужно начать с [азов](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: `preg_quote` используют, когда вам например юзер-инпут надо вставить внутрь регулярки. экранировать скобки надо просто слешами. `preg_quote("привет (мир)")` выдаст вам `привет \(мир\)`, не ясно как вы его используете тут, и вообще с какой целью.

Comment: и не надо дерзить с претензиями вида _"для кого написано?"_, а напишите _"я не понимаю, для чего используется функция preg_quote, возможно, она здесь не требуется, и я не понимаю о чем вообще речь"_

Comment: Я думаю, модификатор \b конфликтует со скобкой. Что с этим делать, я не знаю. Зависит от контекста задачи. Контекст необходимо добавить в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение границы слова зависит от контекста. Если `\b` стоит после скобки, которая не является "словным" символом (буква, цифра или знак подчёркивания), она требует "словный" символ после скобки. Так как в указанной строке после скобки конец строки, совпадения нет.

Используйте контекстонезависимые границы слова `(?<!\w)` и `(?!\w)`:

```
$word = "привет (мир)";
return(preg_match("/(?<!\w)" . preg_quote($word, "/") . "(?!\w)/iu", "привет (мир)"));
```

Шаблон `(?<!\w)` — блок предварительного просмотра назад, который находит позицию в строке, сразу перед которой нет "словного" символа, а `(?!\w)` — блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который находит позицию в строке, сразу *после* которой нет "словного" символа.

Если под границей слова понимать пробельные символы, замените `(?<!\w)` и `(?!\w)` на `(?<!\S)` и `(?!\S)`.

`preg_quote($word, "/")` необходим для правильного экранирования символов, которые является специальными символами регулярных выражений, такие как `?`, `+`, `(`, `)`, `[` и другие.

Comment: Благодарю за объяснение. Вы мне очень помогли. Проблема решена.